# How to Disable DropShadow or any shadow of ContentDialog? UWP, XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am using ContentDialog with a custom xaml style for it, the contentDialog is supposed to have rounded corners but I can see rectangular shadow... interestingly the shadow doesn't show in Windows 1809 build, it does in 1903.

I have seen that when I remove the "Container" border, the shadow goes away but the content dialog is no longer in the center of the page ,it goes to top left.

I also tried using the Shadow property, and tried wrapping the code in DropShadow..it does not make the shadow go away.

[image]

How can I disable or turn off the shadow from the content dialog ? Or, how can  I make the Shadow get rounded... the shadow stays...Please help.

Comment: Please post your XAML code to show what you have done.

Comment: A  rather unorthodox solution was found. I will soon update both the question and post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default style for a content dialog there is an element named **"BackgroundElement"**, it is a **Border** element, changing it to **Grid** will remove the shadow as the shadow is applied on the Border element.

However, doing this will mess up the positioning of the Content dialog, as apparently UWP framework positions/repositions the content dialog with respect to the named element which is supposed to be a border. But, with grid and a bit of a nasty hack, we can fix it, we could grab the reference of the Content dialog (at a suitable position), and set it's Margin like this (only by setting the margin can we really move/reposition the ContentDialog: this bit of knowledge comes from a lot of trial and error). Here's the repositioning code using margin.. that has been working

```
   double leftmargin = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width / 2.0) - (contentDialogReference.ActualWidth / 2.0);
   double topmargin = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2.0) - (contentDialogReference.ActualHeight / 2.0);
   contentDialogReference.Margin = new Thickness(leftmargin, topmargin, 0, 0);
```